# Is there any way to avoid calling viewdidload method like tabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload

I'm developing an application which will work based on maps. So once user opens `MapViewController` then I will load some data every 5 seconds.

I'm using navigation controller(Push view controller).

So every time when user goes to `MapViewController` `viewdidload` method calling. I don't want like that.

That's why I'm trying to avoid `viewdidload` method like `tabbarcontroller`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: put the code of  navigation controller(Push view controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-(void)clickForPush{
    // declarre viewcontroller e.g 'saveRecipeVC' instance globally in interface
    if (!saveRecipeVC) {
        saveRecipeVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:SaveRecipeVCID];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:saveRecipeVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Wow, working like charm. Accepting as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is getting called because your `MapViewController` is getting deallocated when you pop it off of the top of your navigation controller.  When you recreate the view controller, it's getting allocated all over again, and the view loads again. If you keep a reference to `MapViewController` in the class containing your navigation controller, then ARC will not deallocate the object, and you can use this reference to push it back onto the stack so `viewDidLoad` will not get called again.

Edit: Adding code for reference:

```objc
MapViewContoller *mapViewController; // declared globally so there's a strong reference.

- (void) openMapViewController {
    if (!mapViewController) {
        mapViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: MapViewControllerID];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: mapViewController, animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more information how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Sure, @himanth. I see that you already accepted another answer, which is fine, but I added code that's relevant to your question, properly highlighted for Obj-C, and syntactically correct for any beginners that stumble on this question in the future and want to understand why this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is intended to use when,**not possible or efficient to configure 100% of an interface in a XIB.** Sometimes, a particular property you wish to set on a view isn't available in a XIB. Sometimes, you use auto layout, and you realize that the editor for that is actually worse than writing auto layout code. Sometimes, you need to modify an image before you set it as the background of a button.

If you dont want to do these things make your viewDidLoad empty. Than avoiding. Or

> Add code conditionaly into your viewDidLoad.

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(condition) {
    // put your code here      
    }

  }
```